# app-release.apk not installing in android device Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am using `flutter build apk` to build apk. Now the apk is not installing on our android device. it was showing like App not installed as shown image.[image]

What may be the issue and how can I solve this?

Comment: Are you running it on android-12 device  ? if yes , then write exported="true"  for activity tag in android manifest file.

Comment: Just, verify once if in your mobile app is installed then uninstall it once and then try.

Comment: @HardikMehta android version is 11

Comment: is there any previously installed app on device with same package name?

Comment: No, it's a new one.

Comment: Are you using http server or https?

Comment: i am using http

Answer (score -1):

Verify that you can install 3rd party apps in settings and make sure you have enough space available.

Comment: Yes, I can install 3rd party apps and there is much more space on the device.

Comment: do you have enough storage on the phone ?

Comment: Yes, I have, all other apk's are installed, except this.